# Iterate through a 2D array. Kotlin extension method

Tags: array, extension-methods, kotlin

Simple extension method for Kotlin. Should perform an action on every element in a 2d array. i.e. An array of arrays.

I have made the assumption that because the receiver type is defined as an array of arrays of type T, that I do not need to do any checks or casts.

```
fun <T> Array<Array<T>>.forEach2d(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (outer in this) {
        for (inner in outer) {
            action(inner)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `s/forEach2d/forEach2D/`

   - Meaning: "[2d](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/2d)" can mean two-dimensional but it can also mean "second" while "[2D](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/2D)" is unequivocally an abbreviation for two-dimensional.
   - Consistency: In `java.awt.geom`, there is a `Point2D` and no `Point2d`.
   - Convention:

     - [Naming Style - Coding Conventions - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-style)
     - [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language: 9. Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
2. Make it an [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions) for performance reasons.
3. Consider renaming `outer` and `inner`. At first glance a reader might think that `outer` and `inner` refer to the outer array and an inner array but this isn't the case as `outer` is in fact an inner array and `inner` is an element in an inner array. e.g. `s/outer/array/g/` and `s/inner/element/g`.
4. Optionally omit the braces on the 'for' loops. I don't feel strongly about this one either way. I personally keep them but for something as simple as this where there really isn't any logic it makes me wonder why explode it into so many lines. However, I've worked on teams where it is our convention to always use braces for if/for/etc. constructs so be consistent above being brief.
5. [Document your Kotlin Code](http://Documenting%20Kotlin%20Code%20-%20Kotlin%20Programming%20Language). It may seem like a small thing but it can also be surprisingly amazing how much more real/professional/reusable/etc. your code is once you and others can discover methods and documentation is right there explaining exactly what it does and doesn't do.

Example:

```
/**
 * Performs the given [action] on each element in each array.
 */
inline fun <T> Array<Array<T>>.forEach2D(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (array in this) for (element in array) action(element)
}
```